# What is an efficient dynamic programming algorithm to minimize the total cost of an array w/o removing two adjacent elements?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, minimization

I am trying to design an efficient, ***dynamic programming*** algorithm that, given an array of integers of length *n* and a limit of the number of integers that can be removed *k*, will minimize the total cost (i.e. the sum of integers) of the array by removing elements from it such that no two, consecutive elements in the array are removed. I think this is basically the same as maximizing the cost of the total amount of integers I have removed, but I am not completely sure. Quite frankly, I am completely stuck on the recurrence step of the algorithm.

Edit: The number of elements that are removed *can* be less than or equal to the input of k.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right, maximization of removed elements sum is equal to minimization of the rest. But solution is essentially the same.

Recurrence:

```
MaxDel(i, m) = Max(A[i] + MaxDel(i+2, m+1), MaxDel(i+1, m)) if (m < k and i < N) else 0
```

Description: We can remove i-th element, in this case we must omit i+1 and go to i+2, or we can omit i-th and go to the next. Stop when we have k removed elements or index goes out of array.

Comment: Would this still work if k = 2, and we had the array [10,6,7,10,8,6,9]? I think it would just remove 10 and 7, but it should be removing both 10s to make the solution optimal. Also, the number of elements removed can be equal to k, which I guess I should have stated.

Comment: Yes, this will work. After skipping the current entry, taking the next entry is optional. The recurrence allows multiple skips in a row.

Comment: @user3386109 how so? It seems to me that the recurrence has to go through each element of the array and perform a check on both [the sum of itself with its i+2 neighbor] and [its i+1 neighbor]; after find the max of these two, it removes the element at i and either goes to the element at i+2 or the element at i+1 and does the same check.

Comment: @iheartcoding124 The recurrence takes the max of: 1) the sum of the current element with **the best possible answer after skipping one element**, or 2) **the best possible answer starting from the next element**. In neither case are you required to take the next available element.

Comment: In that case, I don't know if this would actually result in a specifically "dynamic programming" solution that computes solutions once; there is too much overhead from recursively taking MaxDel.

Comment: @iheartcoding124 But MaxDel results might be recorded and reused - so simple recursion reverts to dynamic programming

Comment: @MBo Yeah, just as you mentioned this, I was looking at trying to make a "memoized" version of your recursion that just remembers & stores previously computed results in some sort of array. This may avoid having to compute a whole subtree of MaxDel, if we already know the result of this tree, and cutdown on overhead recursive calls. I think it will have the same O() complexity runtime as a solution that computes all results once.

Comment: @iheartcoding124 You don't need memoization to implement this solution. It doesn't help performance at all.